# Logout is not working in CI 3

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

I am trying to log out for the logged in users .
But its not working ,after log out ,i am getting session data also .

Below is my code .please have a look.

```html
public function logout() {

        if ($this->session->userdata('login') == "true") {
            $current_user_data = $this->session->userdata('current_user_data');

            $type = $current_user_data['type'];
            $user_id = $current_user_data['user_id'];
            $token = $current_user_data['token'];
            $logout = $this->school->logout($type, $user_id, $token);
            if (!empty($logout)) {
                //echo $logout->responseCode;
                if ($logout->responseCode == 200 || $logout->responseCode == 419) {
                    $this->session->sess_destroy();
                    $this->clear_cache();//clear the cache after logout //
                    redirect('login');
                } else {
                    //$error['code']=json_encode(array('responseCode' => '500', 'response' => array('message' => 'error', 'statusReason' => 'internal_server_error')));
                    $url = "error/error_type/500";
                    redirect($url);
                }
            } else {
                //echo "invalid token";
                $url = "error/error_type/401";
                redirect($url);
            }
        } else {
            redirect('login');
        }
    }
```

Its going to conditions also , but session is not destroying .

Any thing wrong here?

Thank you

Comment: please explain what does $logout before main if does

Comment: `$logout = $this->school->logout($type, $user_id, $token);` what is the use of this, If it is a model, provide some code

Answer (score 0):

`sess_destroy()` will destroy all the sessions, even flash ones. Why don't use the simple function. I have tried this and it worked in my case. I made a session named userdata which will take user credential while he login. This is my logout function.

```
/**
 * to logout the current session
 */

public function logout() {
    $this->session->unset_userdata('user_login');
    $this->load->view('index.php');
}
```

If you want to destroy the session data this should work fine too,
refer this further https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/sessions.html

Comment: unset the session data worked as required in my case and hence I would recommend the same

Answer (score 0):

**Try this Method for logout**

```
<?php
    class Logout extends CI_Controller
    {
        public function __construct()
        {
            parent::__construct();
            $this->load->helper(array('url','html'));
            $this->load->library('session');
            $this->load->database();
            $this->load->model('users_model');

        }   

        function index()
        {
        $user_data = $this->user_model->get_user_by_id($this->session->userdata('id'));
            foreach ($user_data as $key => $value) {
                if ($key != 'session_id' && $key != 'ip_address' && $key != 'user_agent' && $key != 'last_activity') {
                    $this->session->unset_userdata($key);
                }
            }
        $this->session->sess_destroy();

        redirect('Welcome', 'refresh');
        }
    }
```